# Why is my TypeScript declared class throwing a Not Declared exception?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, typescript

I have the following TypeScript module, unnecessary fluff removed for brevity:

```
/// <reference path="jquery.d.ts" />
module SelectionOtherInputs {
    export class SelectionOtherInputDescriptor {
        constructor(public selectionId: string, public otherKey: any, public otherInputElementId: string) { }
    }
    export class SelectionOtherInputHelper {

        selectionsWithOther: { [selectionKey: string]: SelectionOtherInputDescriptor; } = {};

        getAllSelectionOthers() {
            $("[" + ATT_SELECTION_OTHER_FOR + "]").each(function () {
                var key = $(this).attr(ATT_DATA_SELECTION_OTHER_KEY);
                var desc = new SelectionOtherInputDescriptor("0", key, $(this).attr("id"));
                this.selectionsWithOther[key] = desc;
            });
        }
    }
}
```

Then I try and use the `SelectionOtherInputHelper` class in a small demo page as follows:

```
@section scripts
{
    <script src="~/Scripts/TypeScript/OtherInput.js"></script>
    <script>
        var otherManager = new SelectionOtherInputHelper();
        otherManager.getAllSelectionOthers();
    </script>
}
```

The `scripts' section is being rendered, and jQuery, but I still get a

> Uncaught ReferenceError: SelectionOtherInputHelper is not defined

error on the `var otherManager = new SelectionOtherInputHelper()` call. What else must I do to properly import and use this class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you forgot the module:

```
@section scripts
{
    <script src="~/Scripts/TypeScript/OtherInput.js"></script>
    <script>
        var otherManager = new SelectionOtherInputs.SelectionOtherInputHelper();
        otherManager.getAllSelectionOthers();
    </script>
}
```

Comment: Yews, I wasn't aware it had too be part of the class name.